# How can I send a javascript variable via ajax serverside processing?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatables, server-side

I am loading my datatable via serverside processing:

```
  $('.table').DataTable({

      "serverSide": true, 
      "ajax": '{{ path('json', { 'fileName': output.fileName }) }}',


     /**
      * @Route("/_json/{fileName}", name="json", methods={"GET","POST"})
      */
      public function jsonGenerator(JsonGenerator $jsonGenerator, $fileName) {
        $output = $jsonGenerator->getJson($fileName);
        return $output;
      }
```

It works very well. The problem is, that I want to send a javascript variable. So I tried to change my code so that I am able to send the variable:

```
   var length = 10;
   var table = $('.table').DataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": '{{ path('json') }}',
        "data": {
            "fileName": output.fileName,
             "length": length,
        }
      },



    /**
    * @Route("/_json", name="json", methods={"GET","POST"})
    */
    public function jsonGenerator(JsonGenerator $jsonGenerator,Request $request) {
      $fileName = $request->request->get('fileName');
      $output = $jsonGenerator->getJson($fileName);
      return $output;
    }
```

But it is not working. The datatable is not loaded.

Comment: you got a comma extra after length in your ajax payload.

Comment: Why did your path change? Also add succes and error handlers to see your data that got send / errors.

Comment: @Wimanicesir The path did not change. I am just submitting the data differently

Comment: Ok, and can you do the second part that I said? If the error message is not helping, post it here as well